# .htaccess multi condition problems

Tags: .htaccess

i have wildcard dns on my domain...
and have following in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) sub.php?name=%2 [PT,L]
```

now i want to control different conditions via different php files..
i.e
i want to control....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) sub.php?name=%2 [PT,L]
```

via sub.php
and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com/something.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) sub_more.php?name=%2&more=$1 [PT,L]
```

with sub_more but it is not working how can i arrange conditions so that if something.html is requested it reads from sub_more.php and homepage from sub.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HTTP_HOST* is just the host and not the path. Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ sub.php?name=%2 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^something\.html$ sub_more.php?name=%2&more=$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: but it is still showing me sub.php script instead of sub_more.php while i want to created 2 conditions for both

Comment: @Web Worm: Take a look at my edit. The first rule will only be applied on an empty path (i.e. only `/`).